# How to create a trigger in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

I have two table called PRODUCTIDENTIFIER and CATEGORY. When ever they get updated, I need to create a automatic trigger that create one table using both of the table data. I am not sure how to do this since it involving two tables. I created the stored procedure and now I am kinda stuck.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE Sku_Input_Staging()
    BEGIN
        TRUNCATE TABLE smacstaging.sku;
        INSERT INTO smacstaging.sku (ID, Description, GlobalProductID, Level1, Level2, Level3, Level4, Level5, Level6, Level7, Level8)
        SELECT
              PI.ID
            , PI.Description
            , PI.GlobalProductID
            , CG.Level1 
            , CG.Level2 
            , CG.Level3 
            , CG.Level4 
            , CG.Level5
            , CG.Level6
            , CG.Level7
            , CG.Level8
        FROM PRODUCTIDENTIFIER PI 
        LEFT JOIN CATEGORY CG ON PI.CATEGORYNUMBER = CG.ID;
   END //
 DELIMITER ;
```

Any help on this will highly appreciated.

Thank you so much

Comment: Why bother? The select with JOIN is available there any time you want ti.

Comment: Why not just create a view?

Comment: I also do not understand why separate table that would be filled by trigger required (6 triggers in total would be required).

Comment: yup, like @Nick said, create a view will solve your problem.

Comment: @Nick

Hey Guys, I am not familiar with views, but can you able join the view with another query? I tried join above query with other query. Did not work, it took forever.

Comment: @fifonik

Sku table is combination of Product and Category. If I have in a one table, it will be much faster and cleaner. I am not a DBA. I just learning and trying. Also I have bunch of table in my Staging database (all the API input goes to this tables). They all have necessary columns that don't need to see other people. So I am building production tables too.

Comment: I am not sure what will be the best way to transfer data from Stage tables to production tables.

Comment: I think it will be triggers right? If not please let me know the best way to do this.

Comment: @Suneth yes, you can `JOIN` a view to another table.